# What do we call a person who sells potable water?

Tags: single-word-requests

[image]Back in the days in the Middle East, people use to get their drinking water from certain type of street vendors. Those vendors knew certain spots in rivers, where water is clean; they fill a big leather backpack and wander the streets selling water to customers. What can we call such vendors? Is there an English term?

Comment: Look up *hawker*.

Comment: Are you asking about a street vendor (a generic word for anyone who sells in the street), or someone who sells water? *Hawker* or *pedlar* are generic terms -- among others, I'm sure -- but specific terms for water-sellers are definitely going to be more obscure.

Comment: I would imagine that English would have just absorbed the local word, or called them water-sellers, given that it isn't an occupation that I'm aware of an indigenous British version of. So during British rule in India regimental water bearers were called *bhistis*.

Answer (score 1):

"Water seller."

Googling that term takes me to

1. Different ways that the title *The Water-Seller of Seville* is translated into English:  "Water-Seller"; "Waterseller"; "Water Seller."
2. Bilingual dictionaries.  The Spanish *aguador* is translated "water seller."
3. Google Translate.  Translating into Japanese or Urdu and back gets me "water sellers"; into Arabic and back gets me "water vendors"; into Amharic and back gets me "water seller" again.

I'd say the votes are in.

Comment: In english, water seller or (see Adam Sandler https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Xl0tBmGcno) waterboy.

In Urdu, pannee wallah